# Multiple Prisma Clients using Next.js - Nest.js - Next Auth - Prisma

Tags: node.js, next.js, nestjs, prisma

I want to build a web app using Next.js, next-auth, Nest.js, and Prisma. When I thought about it I couldn't figure out a good way to handle communication with the database via Prisma in this specific use case.

On one side, I want to use `Next.js` and `next-auth` to handle authentication and of course, I need Prisma here for persisting users' data in the database. (so I need a `PrismaClient` instance here).

then in a separate `Nest.js` project, I want to basically handle anything else (other than authentication that was handled by `next-auth`). So I need another `PrismaClient` instance here that should be talking to the **same database**.

My question here is, is it normal to have two `PrismaClient`s talking to the same database? should I worry about synchronization stuff? also if this is a bad idea, what is the correct way to letting `next-auth` (with `Prisma`) handle authentication and handle everything else with a separate backend using `Nest.js` (also with `Prisma`)

Comment: Opt 1: Transform your next project into an authentication service by establishing Next-Auth on a subdomain (accounts.yoursite.com). This will provide domain-wide authentication for a seamless experience across all subdomains and top-level domains. Essentially making it your own auth service.

Opt 2 (recommended): Opt for a 3rd service in lieu of next-auth to significantly reduce dev time, simplify the process, & reduce the risk of security vulnerabilities due to misconfigurations. Supabase Auth is free for 100K users. Supabase can also serve as your database & is compatible with Prisma.